# Magento 2 - What is file Interceptor.php?

Tags: magento2, compiler, di, interceptor

When I overrided file controller of catalog/product and ran this command:

> php bin/mangento setup:di:compile

And then this file "Interceptor.php" was generated in magento_root\var\generation\myPool\myModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\Interceptor.php

Anyone, are you know? What is this file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magento 2 plugin system based on the Interceptor pattern. Calls to almost any module can be intercepted and altered. Vast improvement over the rewrite pattern in Magento 1, so obviously - no more rewrite conflict!

For example:

### DI.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Sort order defines order if multiple plugins intercept the same item. It is possible to intercept **before**, **after** and **around** a function/method.

### 'Before' interceptor

```
class Plugin
{
    public function beforeSetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $name)
    {
        return array('(' . $name . ')');
    }
}
```

### 'After' interceptor

```
class Plugin
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $name)
    {
        return array('|' . $name . '|');
    }
}
```

### 'Around' interceptor

```
class Plugin
{
    public function aroundSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, \Closure $proceed, $name)
    {
        $this->doSomethingBeforeProductIsSaved();
        $returnValue = $proceed($name);
        if ($returnValue) {
            $this->postProductToFacebook($name);
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Checkout the [Magento 2 sample module repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-interception) for a module that demonstrates interception.

Interceptors are replacement for rewrites. Interceptors supplement, but not replace events and observers.

Hope it helps.