# Failed creating a controller

Tags: magento2, controllers

I'm reading the "Magento 2 Development cookbook" and i don't know why the creation of the controller fails. I have:

*app/code/Packt/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Packt_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

*app/code/Packt/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php*

```
<?php

namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
    * Index action
    *
    * @return $this
    */

    public function execute ()
    {

    }
}
```

I clean the cache, which is the only thing needed according to the book.
And, when I go to the browser `/magento2/helloworld`

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php on line 67

Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php on line 67
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/html/m...', 67, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Packt\\HelloWorl...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Packt\\HelloWorl...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Packt\\HelloWorl...')
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(300): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Packt\\HelloWorl...')
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#26 {main}
```

Comment: Example hello world module https://github.com/kingsatti/Simple-HelloWorld-Module-Magneto2

Comment: try with `public function execute ()
        {
          echo "dsfsdf"; exit;
        }`

Comment: Try to delete `var/generation` folder and see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
<?php
namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Loads page content
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'called';exit;
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__(''));
        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Recoverable Error: Argument  passed ... must be an instance of ....

This error usually relates to the arguments of constructor. Each time we call our Controller, **the `Interceptor` which derives from our Controller will be called from `var/generation`**. If we change the constructor of our controller, the Interceptor still keeps the old arguments. They are not compatible. So, our error will be thrown.

**We should delete this folder**, the new Interceptor Controller file will be generated automatically again with the new constructor.

For example Interceptor:

*var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php*

```
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
```

Read more here: [Magento 2 - What is file Interceptor.php?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112377/magento-2-what-is-file-interceptor-php)

Answer (score -1):

You need put constructer in your controller like this,

```
<?php

namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute ()
    {
        echo "This is my page";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't need that. If the constructor is missing from a class, the parent class constructor will be called anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Delete var/generation and pub/static
than

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

it works for me